# Why doesn't AutoResetEvent work BeginSend?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asyncsocket

I've written a serverside application that manages many clients using `BeginSend()` and `EndSend()`

I'm struggling for the past hours to make sure no consequent `BeginSend()` calls are called for the same client.

It seems that the following code snippet doesn't achieve my goal and doesn't block on the second call to `SendAsyncData` before the first completed.

What is my mistake?

```
struct SendBuffer
{
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 128;
    public byte[] BUFFER;
    public int sent;

    public SendBuffer(byte[] data)
    {
        BUFFER = new byte[data.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, BUFFER, 0, data.Length);
        sent = 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        BUFFER = null;
        sent = 0;
    }
}

private void SendAsyncDataWithHeader(byte[] data
{
    int toSend;
    byte[] dataWithHeader = Combine(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), data);

    SendAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    sendBuffer = new SendBuffer(dataWithHeader);

    if (sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent > SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE)
        toSend = SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE;
    else
        toSend = sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent;

    try
    {
        socket.BeginSend(sendBuffer.BUFFER, 0, toSend, SocketFlags.None, sendCallback, null);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        switch (se.SocketErrorCode)
        {
            case SocketError.ConnectionAborted:
            case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                if (Disconnected != null)
                {
                    Disconnected(this);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Server.logger.Error(ex);
        Disconnected(this);
    }
}

void sendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int bytesSent;
    try
    {
        bytesSent = socket.EndSend(ar);
        if (bytesSent == 0)
        {
            if (Disconnected != null)
            {
                Disconnected(this);
                return;
            }
        }
        sendBuffer.sent += bytesSent;
        if (sendBuffer.sent == sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length)
        {
            sendBuffer.Dispose();

            SendAutoResetEvent.Set();
            Server.logger.Info("set {0}", userName);
        }
        else
        {
            int toSend;
            if (sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent > SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE)
                toSend = SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE;
            else
                toSend = sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent;

            socket.BeginSend(sendBuffer.BUFFER, sendBuffer.sent, toSend, SocketFlags.None, sendCallback, null);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        switch (se.SocketErrorCode)
        {
            case SocketError.ConnectionAborted:
            case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
                if (Disconnected != null)
                {
                    Disconnected(this);
                    return;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Server.logger.Error(ex);
        Disconnected(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the catch/finally of the two try blocks? You seem to have omitted them.

Comment: How do you run any code in a class with all private methods?

Comment: @PeterRitchie static void Main()? ;)

Comment: @Dr_Asik yeah, but this isn't the `Program` class and there is no `Main`

Comment: I didn't post it because it felt irrelevant. Maybe I'm wrong?
I only use a catch block, with SocketException and ObjectDisposed.
SocketException disposes the socket. ObjectDisposed does nothing

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed where `SendAsyncData` was being called in your application.

Comment: I've updated to the (almost) full version...

Comment: Please post a short, compilable, but complete, example that reproduces the problem

Comment: Assuming that each socket has a separate `AutoResetEvent`, there doesn't appear any reason for multiple threads to be released unless there's something else that you've omitted in your question that is causing it. How are you determining that multiple threads are being released, and what steps have you taken to debug the issue?